# Android/AsyncTask: Do you still have to check "isCancelled" (API 24)?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, cancellation

My app uses an `AsyncTask` to download files while displaying a `ProgressDialog` (I'm aware that it's deprecated) with a "Cancel" button.

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask#cancel(boolean)) you should check `isCancelled()` in `doInBackground` periodically because `mytask.cancel(true)` won't interrupt `doInBackground` on its own.

I simply cancelled the task without checking at first and noticed that it still stops `doInBackground`: Depending on how long I let it download before pressing the "Cancel" button, I've seen different sizes in the resulting file - from just a few kb to a couple of mb - the final size would have been around 9mb.

How is this possible? Do you actually not have to call `isCancelled()` anymore?

My AsyncTask:

```
private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressdialog.setMessage("Preparing Download...");
        progressdialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        progressdialog.setProgressNumberFormat(null);
        progressdialog.setProgressPercentFormat(null);
        progressdialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        progressdialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                progressdialog.dismiss();
                mytask.cancel(true);
            }
        });
        progressdialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... bla) {
        String error = download();
        return error;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... s) {
        //....
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        progressdialog.dismiss();
        //....
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to this you should check isCancelled() in doInBackground
>   periodically because mytask.cancel(true) won't interrupt
>   doInBackground on its own.

Actually it is not true.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel(boolean)):

> After invoking this method, you should check the value returned by
>   isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]) to finish the
>   task as early as possible.

It means you can *additionally* check for `isCancelled()` to stop `AsyncTask` *earlier* if it is started.

mytask.cancel(true) will stop execution anyway.

Let`s see under the hood what is going on

When you call `mytask.cancel(true)`:

```
public final boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    mCancelled.set(true);
    return mFuture.cancel(mayInterruptIfRunning);
}
```

Where `mFuture` is `FutureTask` that holds runnable inside

Then `mFuture.cancel` is called:

```
public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
    if (state != NEW)
        return false;
    if (mayInterruptIfRunning) {
        if (!UNSAFE.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, NEW, INTERRUPTING))
            return false;
        Thread t = runner;
        if (t != null)
            t.interrupt();
        UNSAFE.putOrderedInt(this, stateOffset, INTERRUPTED); // final state
    }
    else if (!UNSAFE.compareAndSwapInt(this, stateOffset, NEW, CANCELLED))
        return false;
    finishCompletion();
    return true;
}
```

Where `runner` is just

```
private volatile Thread runner;
```

Since its just thread, lets see what `interrupt` does in your case:

> If this thread is blocked in an I/O operation upon an interruptible
>   channel then the channel will be closed, the thread's interrupt status
>   will be set, and the thread will receive a ClosedByInterruptException.

So if your `download()` method uses `InterruptibleChannel` `interrupt` will work.

In other words looks like you have never had to call `isCancelled()` to interrupt `AsyncTask` =) since `Thread.interrupt` can stop io blocking operation in your case.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you're right, I've never had to call `isCancelled()` before. ;) So baiscally `mytask.cancel(true)` is just a way to cancel I/O operations (in my case: a `BufferedOutputStream`) by interrupting the thread. What if there's no I/O operation going on but e.g. long calculations you don't want to block the UI thread? Can you still stop these with `cancel(true)` or do you actually have to keep checking `isCancelled()` in this case?

Comment: @Neph long operation in doInBackground, same as in separateThread cannot block UI thread. Also even if you do not check isCancelled thread will be interrupted, for example while(true){} inside doInBackground will be interrupted anyway. But if you write (while(!isCancelled()) {} instead, that will stop correctly even if you write cancel(false).

Comment: Sorry, I meant having a long non-I/O operation in an AsyncTask, so it doesn't block the UI thread. For me it's a mix, first I get the connection to the server, which might take a bit (but will time out on its own), then I'm reading/writing (=downloading) the file. In the end there's nothing really infinite going on, which is exactly what an AsyncTask is supposed to be used for from what I've gathered. Good to know, thanks!